# Игра "Четное - нечетное"

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, код игры "Четное - нечетное".

Условия игры:

Компьютер генерирует случайное целое число, а человек пытается угадать четное оно или нечетное. Результат сравнения выводится на экран.

Comment: @Sprint116, согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Меня больше интересует рандом и определение четности. То что находил - выдавало ошибки. Работаю с Visual Studio

Comment: Ну так  и надо исправлять ошибки!!! 

Нужно не просить код, а исправлять ошибки!

Наверняка ошибки банальные типо забыли namespace или неправильно создали проект.

Answer (score 1):

Ну например:

```
bool getResponse(char* prompt, char* secondaryPrompt)
{
    cout << prompt;
    while (true)
    {
        string inp;
        getline(cin, inp);
        if (inp.length() == 1)
        {
            char resp = tolower(inp[0]);
            if (resp == 'y')
                return true;
            if (resp == 'n')
                return false;
        }
        cout << secondaryPrompt;
    }
}

void main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    while (true)
    {
        bool respEven = getResponse(
                "Is next number even? (y/n): ",
                "Please say 'y' or 'n': ");
        double r01 = rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX + 1); // in [0 .. 1)
        int random100 = (int)(r01 * 100); // in [0 .. 100)
        bool random100even = (random100 % 2) == 0;
        bool guessIsRight = random100even == respEven;
        if (guessIsRight)
            cout << "your guess is right" << endl;
        else
            cout << "your guess is wrong" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем так сложно, не понимаю. Если считаете, что определенный бит "недостаточно случаен", то можно проверять случайный бит (0..14 или 0..30 в зависимости от RAND_MAX).

Но, в любом случае в начало не мешает добавить srand(), а то с очередной попытки (перезапуска) программа будет постоянно проигрывать.

Впрочем, тогда ее можно использовать в качестве измерителя внимания игрока.

Comment: @avp: я следую совету Кнута о том, что младшие биты недостаточно случайны. а также документации:

> In the past, some implementations of rand() have had serious shortcomings in the randomness, distribution and **period** of the sequence produced (in one well-known example, the low-order bit simply alternated between 1 and 0 between calls).

Период младшего бита (`rand() % 2`), например, равен либо 0, либо 1 для линейной конгруэнтной последовательности. То есть совершенно не годится.

Comment: @avp:  Кроме того, распределение будет дополнительно неравномерно, если делитель не делится нацело на размер seed'а. Пример: если seed имеет 2 бита (то есть он 0, 1, 2 или 3 с одинаковой вероятностью), и мы берём `rand() % 3`, вероятности результатов будут 0: 1/2, 1: 1/4, 2: 1/4. Такой же эффект с любой длиной seed'а (только не настолько заметный).

Comment: @VladD, это так, но зачем так много вычислений?

IMHO `(rand() & (1<<10)) == respEven` было бы достаточно.

Comment: @avp:

1. Я не уверен, что 10-ый бит _гарантированно_ ведёт себя хорошо. С другой стороны, мне гарантируется, что `rand()` равномерно распределено на `[0..RAND_MAX + 1)`. А раз так, `rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX + 1)` гарантированно равномерно распределено на `[0..1)`. От этих гарантий и работаю.
2. Автор просил пример по работе с рандомом и проверкой чётности. Поэтому я вывел все нужные промежуточные переменные, для улучшения понимания.

Comment: @VladD, ну double-то в любом случае не нужен. 

Если опасаетесь "неслучайного" поведения произвольного бита в середине числа, то достаточно

     ((rand() <= RAND_MAX/2) == respEven)

P.S. Кнута я когда-то тоже читал.

Comment: @avp: 4. поскольку пример — учебный, используй я `%`, ТС подумал бы, что его можно использовать и для получения случайного целого числа в диапазоне с длиной, не являющейся степенью двойки. А это не так, см. пример про 2-хбитный `seed`.

---
Это да, на самом деле достаточно даже просто `rand() <= RAND_MAX/2` :-P. Потому что угадывает человек в любом случае с вероятностью 1/2. Я хотел скорее показать получение случайного числа в произвольном диапазоне, пример-то учебный.

P.S: Насчёт Кнута я и не сомневался.